# how to implement wait() for producer/consumer using C++17 (mutex or shared_mutex)

Tags: c++, mutex, thread-synchronization

I have a set of consumers generating data, each with their own vector. A consumer, in this MWE the main function, should wait for one of the producers to create something, and then once it wakes up process all queues and then wait again.

With a mutex, the critical section is easy to create, but how to wait for any one of the producers to signal that data is available, and wake up main. The producers do not need to block each other, they could each add to their own queue, but each producer must block the consumer, and the consumer must block all the producers.

Here is my MWE, which is only missing the equivalent of Java obj.wait() and object.notify().

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

mutex m;

vector<int> event1;
int count1 = 0;

void producer1() {
    while(true) {
        m.lock(); // enter critical section
        cout << "producer1: " << count1 << '\n';
        event1.push_back(count1++);
        // TODO: wakeup main consumer loop
        // in Java this would be obj.notify();
        m.unlock();
        sleep(1);

    }
}

vector<int> event2;
int count2 = 0;

void producer2() {
    while(true) {
        m.lock(); // enter critical section
        cout << "producer2: " << count2 << '\n';
        event2.push_back(count2++);
        // TODO: wakeup main consumer loop
        // in Java this would be obj.notify();
        m.unlock(); // enter critical section
        sleep(2);
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t1(producer1);
    thread t2(producer2);

    while (true) {
        // TODO: obj.wait();

        // inside the critical section, get all the data from each producer
        m.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < event1.size(); i++)
            cout << "consumer1: " << event1[i] << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < event2.size(); i++)
            cout << "consumer2: " << event2[i] << '\n';
        event1.clear();
        event2.clear();
        m.unlock();

        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard library class one can use to wait until a condition becomes true is called `std::condition_variable`

Comment: Try to avoid manual locking/unlocking. If anything happens (an exception etc) you might end up with a locked mutex that won't be unlocked. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);` will lock `m` automatically and unlock `m` when `lock` goes out of scope.